# Не проходит запрос на добавление из выподающего списка

Tags: php, mysql

Не получается добавление с выподающим списком

---

```
<form method="kolstud" action="kolstud.php">

<select name="namebook">

 <option value="0">Выберите книгу</option>

<?
$res = mysql_query('select `idbook`, `name` from `book`');

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){

    ?>
    <option value="<?=$row['idbook']?>"><?=$row['name']?></option>

    <?
}
?>
</select>

 <select name="FIOstud">
    <option value="0">Выберите ФИОстудента</option>
<?
$res = mysql_query('select `idstudent`, `FIO` from `student`');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    ?>
    <option value="<?=$row['idstudent']?>"><?=$row['FIO']?></option>
    <?
}
?>
</select>
 <input type="submit" name="Submit2" value="добавить"/>
</form>

<?php

            $namebook = $_REQUEST['namebook'];
            $FIOstud = $_REQUEST['FIOstud'];

$insert = "INSERT INTO `kolstud` VALUES (
 ( SELECT `idbook` FROM `book` WHERE `name` = '$namebook' ),
( SELECT `idstudent` FROM `student` WHERE `FIO` = '$FIOstud' ))";

if($namebook != "")
                    {
                            mysql_query($insert,$dblink);
                    } 
?>
```

Comment: сделайте так:

    //mysql_query($insert,$dblink);
    mysql_query($insert,$dblink) or die(mysql_error());

Что говорит?

Comment: Column 'book_idbook' cannot be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO `kolstud` (`поле_1`, `поле_2`) VALUES (
 ( SELECT `idbook` FROM `book` WHERE `name` = '$namebook' ),
( SELECT `idstudent` FROM `student` WHERE `FIO` = '$FIOstud' ))";
```

Обратите внимание на поля(`поле_1` и `поле_2`), которые хотите заполнить. Также если в таблице больше полей (не считая autoincrement), они тоже должны быть в запросе.

Синтаксис [INSERT](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/insert.html) с примерами

**UPD:** окей, тогда в комментарий результат этого кода (вставить перед `$insert = ...`)

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($namebook, $FIOstud, $_REQUEST, $insert);
echo '</pre>';
```

**UPD2:** я прошу прощения, не заметил сразу)) Вам приходит idbook, а не namebook, поэтому в первом SELECT нет нужды, он уже выбран. %) Пардон, так и idstudent уже выбран, зачем вы вообще извращаетесь?)

```
$insert = "
  INSERT INTO `kolstud` VALUES (
    $namebook,
    $FIOstud
    )
  ";
```

Только переменные потом переименуйте

Comment: Вам же английским по белому написали, что запрос неправильный: "Column 'book_idbook' cannot be null", поле "book_idbook" не может быть пустым. Подскажу - это `поле_1`.

Comment: Приглядитесь к запросу у меня и у вас. Они разные. `$namebook` должно приходить, а вот запрос кривой, в вашем варианте не указаны названия полей.

Comment: И еще раз)

Comment: все понятно спс я блин и зыбыл что сейчас мы посылем id
мне сказали добавлять из выпадающего списка вот и делаю  вот сижу и извращаюсь

Comment: Не за что, тож долго соображал. Галочку слева от ответа не забываем нажать =)